# OnFocus how to change border color of TextBoxField in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, textbox

I am using the following code for TextBoxField:
http://na.blackberry.com/eng/devjournals/resources/journals/jul_2005/creating_textbox_field.jsp

now i am trying to change TextBoxField border color when it focused. But could not able to get.
need some help on this.

Thanks,

Comment: Post your code, so everyone can figured out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
protected void paint(Graphics g) {
    if (isFocus()) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    } else {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks rupesh, i got the answer at bb forum i.e
http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/OnFocus-how-to-change-border-color-of-TextBoxField/m-p/544178#M110095
very well explained.